# devtoolset-3 not found on Centos 6

Tags: centos6, devtoolset

This failed all of a sudden. Anyone know how to circumvent it? Thanks.

```
[cktan@ckrh6 ~]$     sudo yum install -y devtoolset-3
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.riverfrontnetworks.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirrors.gigenet.com
 * updates: mirror.grid.uchicago.edu
No package devtoolset-3 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: I have the same experience. I am using Centos 6 in Docker for my CI system.

Comment: Maybe https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=67978 is a hint

Answer (score 0):

Devtoolset-3 is end-of-life, and the community has not maintained all of its packages. Thus, there are some dependency bugs ([Bug 1410152](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1410152)). As a work-around, you can point yum to the *older* Devtoolset-3 packages here instead, which do not have the dependency issues: 
https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/rhscl/devtoolset-3/

Also, see the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53714465/3987854).