# Install Obsolete Devtoolset Collection for CentOS

Tags: centos, software-collections, devtoolset

At present time Devtoolset-5 (and earlier) cannot be istalled from Software Collection Repository (centos-release-scl) using `yum` (only Devtoolset-6 and 7 are available). Nevertheless, this collection can be downloaded as a list of rpm-packages. Is it possible to enable such EOL collections for `yum`, or maybe there is another way to install them correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the obsolete devtoolset-3 in this way:

```
sudo yum --obsolete install devtoolset-3
```

Answer (score 1):

There was no DTS 5 release.  It was skipped to align the DTS version with the GCC major release, once GCC switched to a yearly increasing version number.

DTS versions 3 and 4 are available from the `centos-release-scl` repository.

Comment: You are right, there is no DTS5... Actually, I need DTS3. When I check yum list available | grep "devtoolset", I see only DTS 6 and 7, but no DTS 3 and DTS 4. However, they are actually exist in the scl-repository and are available here: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/sclo/x86_64/rh/. How to make them available through the yum?

Answer (score 1):

While Devtoolset-3 and 4 are located on the Centos mirror [site](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/sclo/x86_64/rh), `yum` will not be able to find them as they were not included in the `repodata` on the site. These were probably excluded because they are EOL (end-of-life), and have dependency bugs ([Bug 1410152](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1410152)). Try using the *older* Devtoolset-3 packages here, which do not have the dependency issues:

https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/rhscl/devtoolset-3/

If you really want the packages from the centos.org site, I went with `wget` to download all the RPMs, then recreated a local yum repo. However, you'll see the dependency issues and `yum install devtoolset-3` will fail.

```
$ wget -r -p -e robots=off --directory-prefix="/mnt/local-devtoolset3-repo" --recursive --no-clobber --no-parent http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/sclo/x86_64/rh/devtoolset-3/
$ sudo yum install createrepo
$ cd /mnt/local-devtoolset3-repo
$ createrepo --database .
```